# Convert varchar to tinyint(4) in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am migrating data from one data base to another data base. In first data base there is a table lets say table1, has a field of type varchar(100) with value "White" and in another data base there is a table lets table2 has the same field of type tinyint(4), so, how can I convert varchar to tinyint. I searched a lot but didn't find any relevant info. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what would be the integer values for `white` or any other possible values ?

Comment: It should be the same value as in table1.

Comment: `TINYINT` can represent values [-128 - 127].  It has eight bits to work with. Your `varchar(100)` column has 800 bits to work with. You're going to have to map the distinct values of your input table to small integers to make this conversion. There's no way to write "white" directly in eight bits.

Comment: I dont understand you are trying to covert a varchar to integer and if its something as `white` then all the conversion will give you 0.

Comment: why you woulden't add new column in table1 with type of tinyint(4), and than update value of that column based on value of table1 and table2...

Comment: So, it is not possible to store "white" in tinyint(4) in any, way ?

Comment: Well, I can't change data base schema or table description .

Comment: well tinyint(4) is integer "white" is string you definitely first need to change value of "white" into number like 5, than maybe you can change column type but i don't know that for sure... you already change table description you will have column of different type

Comment: I mean, now I can't change table description.

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of the integer value of varchar value 'white'.
Normally we can convert varchar value to int like the folowing query

```
select cast(column_name as tinyint)
```

EDIT:
Spaces will not be a problem for cast, however characters like TAB, CR or LF will appear as spaces,use REPLACE to clean up your data.

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tinyint), push_id, jid, about_me, status, set push_timestamp cast(push_timestamp' at
line 3.

Comment: and the query is something like this : DECLARE cur1 cursor for SELECT name, gender, date_of_birth, height, weight, cast(ethnicity as tinyint), push_id, jid, about_me, status, cast(push_timestamp as tinyint), latitude, longitude FROM ios.location inner JOIN ios.user ON ios.location.user_id=ios.user.user_id;

Comment: You can't `cast` to `tinyint`.